# How to show and hide field immediately base on the text length? - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input text like this:

```
input1
<input type='text' id='input1' name='input1'>
<br>
input2
<input type='text' id='input2' name='input2'>
<br>
```

Now I want to hide and show `input2` base on the event in `input1` if there is no text in `input1` then `input2` will be hidden and vice versa. I write JQuery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("input1");
    var textLength = inputText.value.length;
    if (textLength <= 0){
      $('#input2').hide("fast");
    }
    else{
      $('#input2').show("fast");
    }
  });
```

It works only after each time refresh. So how to catch the input event in `input1` and affect the change immediately to `input2`?

Comment: *"`textLength <= 0`"* - Get a lot of negative length strings do you? Anyway, you need to put your length test inside an event handler triggered by, say, the [`"input"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). `$("#input1").on("input", function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var input1 = $('#input1');
  
  function toggleInput() {
      if(input1.val().length) {
        $('#input2').show("fast");
      } else {
        $('#input2').hide("fast");
      }
  }
  
  toggleInput();
  
  $('#input1').on('keyup', toggleInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input1
<input type='text' id='input1' name='input1'>
<br>
input2
<input type='text' id='input2' name='input2'>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap it on jquery `keydown` or `keyup` function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input1").keydown(function() {
        var inputText = this.value;
        var textLength = inputText.length;
        if (textLength <= 0) {
            $('#input2').hide("fast");
        } else {
            $('#input2').show("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3fmw1mw/134/)

Comment: how are you getting inputTextlength?

Comment: This doesn't work. The keydown event is triggered before the input's `.value` updates, so the `.length` won't be correct yet. Also, what if the user edits the field without using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listeners for these elements. Example using mostly your original code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input1').on("keyup", function() {
        var inputText = document.getElementById("input1");
        var textLength = inputText.value.length;
        if (textLength <= 0) {
            $("#input2").hide("fast");
        } else {
            $("#input2").show("fast");
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you have two input textbox only.

First assign a common class like

```
input1
<input type='text' id='input1' class='input' name='input1'>
<br>
input2
<input type='text' id='input2' class='input' name='input2'>
<br>

   $(".input").change(function(){
        alert(this.id);
        if(this.id == 'input1')
        {                 
              if ($(this).val().length > 0){
              $("#input2").show();
              } else {
              $("#input2").hide();
              }             
        }
        else
        {
             if ($(this).val().length > 0){
              $("#input1").show();
              } else {
              $("#input1").hide();
              }      
        }           
    });
```

Comment: A function that explicitly references both inputs' ids isn't really "more generic", but in any case this doesn't work. The object referred to by `this` doesn't have a `.val()` method. Also the keydown event is triggered before the input's value updates, so the `.length` won't be correct. Also, what if the user edits the field without using the keyboard?

Comment: @nnnnnn ..agreed with you .have updated answer ..it works as per the html stated in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input1').on('input', function() {
    $('#input2').toggle($(this).val().length === 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript with this code! This code improves the performance of your application as it uses selectors only once!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var input1 = $('#input1');
  var input2 = $('#input2');

  input2.hide("fast");
  input1.on('keyup', function() {
      if(input1.val().length) {
        input2.show("fast");
      } else {
        input2.hide("fast");
      }
  });
});
```